# How Do I Store A Calculated Value In Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working on a project where I want to always show a post that has the least feedback (the goal is to encourage feedback on works in progress). I have figured out the calculation for this - although feedback is welcome - however, I am having trouble assigning this value to a column (`:feedback_score`) on the Post model. I need help.

post.rb:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    def feedback_score_calc
        time_passed = ((Time.now - self.created_at)/1.hour).round(3)
        feedback = self.comments.count
        self.feedback_score = time_passed / feedback
    end
end
```

I need to know how to call this method whenever a new comment is added, and I also need to be able to calculate it on some form of schedule. My goal is to display the least engaged on first visit with paging to progress to the 2nd to least engaged, 3rd, etc...

My other problem is that I can't even get this method to run through the console, I get a no method error, even when using `def self.feedback_score_calc`.

Comment: you have to add `self.save` after you assigned value for feedback_score to save it into database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your code as you've provided it, it's an **instance** method on `Post`. You should be able to do something like

```
@post = Post.find(some_id_here)
@post.feedback_score_calc
```

Creating it as a **class** method with definition `def self.feedback_score_calc` isn't what you want to do, because you're making calculations on a specific *instance* of `Post` and it's relations.

As @Kien Thanh mentioned in the comments, you'll need to call `save` on the `Post` instance after you set the column value if you want to see it reflected in the database.

```
@post = Post.find(some_id_here)
@post.feedback_score_calc
@post.save
```

or in the method itself

```
def feedback_score_calc
    time_passed = ((Time.now - self.created_at)/1.hour).round(3)
    feedback = self.comments.count
    self.feedback_score = time_passed / feedback
    save
end
```

Also worth mentioning, you can write to a column directly *(bypassing the `feedback_score=` method ActiveRecord sets up)* by calling `write_attribute` like this

```
def feedback_score_calc
    time_passed = ((Time.now - self.created_at)/1.hour).round(3)
    feedback = self.comments.count

    write_attribute(:feedback_score, time_passed / feedback)
    save
end
```

Finally, you need to either kill and restart your console or run `reload!` from within the console when making changes to your model that you're trying to verify from within the console.

Comment: This seems perfect. Thank you! How would I run this on a schedule though?